# Total value of sold product according to stock history in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I am selling some stuff and trying to make my SELLING SUMMARY in excel.
One sheet contains products purchase history with details like:

- product name,
- quantity, value,
- price for 1 piece

The other sheet contains selling summary log with details like:

- product name,
- total sold quantity

All I want is to write formula which can calculate the product total value according to stock history.

Example:
I have bought 1200 pieces of product "MICRO USB CABLE" 3 times with different prices each times.

This is the purchase order with details:

- 1st time I have bought 500 cables for € 0.60 each
- 2nd time I have bought 400 cables for € 0.63 each
- 3rd time I have bought 300 cables for € 0.50 each

AND NOW:
I have sold 1000 pieces of product "MICRO USB CABLE". That mean that I have sold 500 cables for € 0.60 each, then 400 cables for € 0.63 each and 100 cables for € 0.50 each. As you see, for 3rd time I just took 100 cables because I have sold only 1000 (not all 1200).

Now, I can calculate total amount manually with this formula:

```
=(500*0.60)+(400*0.63)+(100*0.50)
```

but how to make it to calculate automatically?

There is function called `=SUMPRODUCT()` but I am not familiar with that

For better understand please take a look to this document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjSYvGqCVD59dEtLTERFSzNWdjdhSFlraTZQNFNINmc&usp=sharing
(you can edit this document "in fly")

Any idea?

Comment: I will try to edit my post with more details described. Just one moment

Comment: Now, I hope my problem is described with enough info

Comment: Much better. :-) Thanks for cooperating so well. I'll remove my other comments, now that they no longer apply.

Comment: Well-detailed question. How should multiple stock entries be depleted?  Is it always FIFO (as you have described in your example) or could there be some other order?

Comment: Thank you, yes it's always FIFO

Comment: My approach would be to set up a new structure to do the analysis. Start with just one product's transactions in a separate table. This makes it easier to compute the debit against each purchase, and how much of the total debit (1000) remains to carry to the next transaction. Since order is important, I recommend adding a sequential key of some kind to the transaction source (your table at left). This could be a date, or simply cardinal numbers. That `SUMPRODUCT` you mentioned will come in quite handy once you get this far.

Comment: In your purchase sheet, you need a column to indicate Quantities left.. As in your example, the 300 cables should have 200 left and the other two .. zero.

Comment: guys can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to disappoint you, what you need is ACCESS.
Excel is very powerful and can do basically everything, but you are trying to take the long path.
For FIFO (of LIFO) inventory system, please use Microsoft Access.

Comment: can you provide some examples as I never used a Microsoft Access